# Why is my Safecracker form only visible to super-admins?

Tags: safecracker, solspace-calendar

I built a safecracker form to allow users to post events to a [Solspace calendar](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/calendar/), however, for some reason, the actual form is only showing on the page when a superuser is logged in.  If anyone who is a regular member views the page, the form doesn't display.  I've looked at the source and everything is there EXCEPT what would be between the form tags (or the `{exp:safecracker}` tags.

To be clear, the page itself is visible to the appropriate user groups.  It's just the actual form that seems to be omitted if I attempt to view the page as a regular (logged in) user.

The reason for the safecracker form in the first place is because I found the Solspace calendar pre-fab form doesn't quite work... and if I'm logged in as superuser, the form I built works great! (which is making it that much more frustrating).

The form itself is quite simple, with the required fields set as hidden and some jquery magic to handle the formatting of the values.

```
  {exp:safecracker channel="calendar_events" return="home" include_jquery="no" safecracker_head="no"}

    <input type="hidden" name="calendar_id" value="23" />
    <input type="hidden" name="start_date[0]" id="startDate" value="" />       
    <input type="hidden" name="end_date[0]" id="endDate" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="start_time[0]" id="startTime" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="end_time[0]" id="endTime" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event_created_by" value="{member_id}" />

 ...

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Comment: Would you like so that any guest could post the entry via Safecraker. You need to look here http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/control_panel/index.html#allow-guests-to-post-entries

Comment: Do you have "Can post and edit entries in: [your_channel_name]" selected for that member group (Edit Member Group > Channel Posting Privileges)?

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 That's it!  I can't believe I missed that... thank-you!

Comment: Glad that was it! Moved it to the answer, in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy to forget, but make sure you give the member group you want to edit the safecracker form the ability to edit that channel in member group prefs. "Can post and edit entries in: [your_channel_name]" selected for that member group (Edit Member Group > Channel Posting Privileges).

Comment: @nageeb - please mark the answer by Romans-8---31-39 as the correct answer.